# ...scrollTop($(this)...)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few `div`s with the `.class` class whose scroll position is defined by another child of its parent, so I need to assign a `scrollTop()` with `$(this)`, something like

```
$(".class").scrollTop($(this).parent().find('.child').scrollTop());
```

But that code doesn't work...

```
$(".class").scrollTop(
    function(){
        $(this).parent().find('.child').scrollTop()
    }
);
```

Doesn't work either. Any clue?

Comment: Use scrollTo perhaps?

Comment: I'm actually using scrollLeft() 'cause it's horizontal scroll. How would you use scrollTo()?

Comment: You're using scrollLeft but you're asking about scrollTop? Seems counterproductive..

Comment: I think you need to add a `return`?

Comment: Haha... Well... It's the same thing, but people gets confused with scrollLeft, because it's not equally popular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assuming that I am reading your question right. You have mulitple "class" elements that have their own "child" elements. You would need to use each to set every element separately.

```
$(".class").each(
    function(){
        var elem = $(this);
        var childsScrollPosition = elem.parent().find('.child').scrollTop();
        elem.scrollTop(childsScrollPosition);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

[ScrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/) wants an integer for the position so passing the DOM node wont help.
Try caching your selector and pass it with the position method:

```
var scrollTo = $(this).parent().find('.child');

$(".class").scrollTop( scrollTo.position().top );
```

Or you use offset depending on your use case:

```
var scrollTo = $(this).parent().find('.child');

$(".class").scrollTop( scrollTo.offset().top );
```

I am doing this blind here but this should work too:

```
    var scrollTo = $(this).parent().find('.child');

    $(".class").scrollTop(
        function() {
            return scrollTo.offset().top;
        }
    );
```

Does this help?